# É possivel conectar PHP com uma versão antiga de mysql server (3.23)?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo isso:

```
$conexao = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $db);
if (!$conexao) {
  die('Não conectou: '.mysql_error());
} 
echo "Conectou";
```

E a mensagem de erro é essa:

> Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported.

Não posso mudar o MySQL Server, tem alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para conectar?

Comment: Creio que PDO se conecte com a versão 4 do mysql, mas só testando https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.connections.php -- me confirma se é isto.

Comment: Tentei com PDO e o seguinte erro aparece: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported

Comment: Caro teixeira, creio que só usando uma tecnologia a parte, por exemplo o mysql via comando de linha + o `exec()` do PHP. Talvez eu formule uma resposta ou exemplo e poste de novo aqui, mas fora isso nativamente creio que será impossivel sem usar algo de terceiros, ao menos de terceiros até agora não achei nada que seja bom, até achei um código, mas ele é péssimo, cheio de problemas, que é exec+mysqlcli, mas não compensa e eu me sinto na responsabilidade postar apenas coisas boas ou razoaveis, coisas com muito problemas seria irresponsabilidade de minha parte. Assim que possivel irei ver isso.

Comment: Obrigado mesmo assim. Não tenho permissão para atualizar o servidor, mas tenho que fazer algumas modificações no site. Essas modificações são simples, mas configurar um servidor para testar antes de por online está me dando uma dor de cabeça.

Comment: Achei alguns casos no google que resolveram utilizando `mysqli_connect` ao invés de `mysql_connect`.

Comment: Infelizmente dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Benilson creio q foi outra coisa, não deve ter sido exatamente por causa do mysqli ou do PDO, deve ter sido questão de versão e driver, mas nem vou entrar nesse mérito e nem adianta ficarmos chutando alternativas sem saber se são eficazes, afinal não somos suporte técnico, temos que buscar o que é correto para o autor e futuros visitantes... Caro Teixeira eu não sugeri mudar nada no servidor, sugeri uma ideia de script PHP mesmo que usa o mysql por linha de comando e isso geralmente já é padrão nas hospedagens, assim q tiver um tempo passo aqui para falarmos melhor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a maioria das situações dá para ser testada pela pessoa que tenta ajudar, mas a do Teixeira tem um grau de complexidade maior, para grande parte dos usuários do SO, não é possível simular o problema que ele está tendo. Com o objetivo de ajudar, só podemos fazer conjecturas baseadas em algum conhecimento ou pesquisa, ou não fazer nada. Por exemplo agora eu iria sugerir que ele tente usar uma conexão `ODBC`, por usar drives genéricos para acessar o banco de dados, mas não tenho como afirmar que vai funcionar.

Comment: @Benilson isso ai é o que chamamos de helpdesk, geralmente a pergunta nesse cenário é fechada, mas de qualquer forma só estou tentando dar uma ajuda pra ele, o resto que eu disse era superficial, pode ou não ajudar futuras pessoas, mas vai depender da "solução", se é que existe algo q seja no minimo decente pra resolver, de qualquer forma mysqli não vai resolver o caso, pq o driver não é compativel nem em diferentes APIs.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você esta utilizando um drive que não tem suporte para a versão do mySql que você quer conectar:

Possiveis causas:

1. Quando utilizamos um xampp, wamp server .... Já vem junto os drivers, que são setados no SO,parece que você tem o driver MySQL restante do PHP 4.4, porque é isso que causa essa mensagem de erro.
2. Ao reinstalar outras versões de PHP mais recente junto com versões antigas, ha um conflito entre as versões, pois nem todas as variáveis de ambiente são configuradas ao instalar outras versões de PHP

Mas resumindo é apenas referencias incorretas entre o mySql instalado e o drive setado no ambiente.

Comment: Mysql não é PHP, ele não esta falando de PHP4.4, ele esta falando de mysql4, não tem haver com conflitos do PHP, tem haver com a versão do mysql, que pode estar em qualquer lugar/servidor. Creio que PDO consiga se conectar com versões antigas (não pude testar), ao menos com o mysql4

Comment: Então @GuilhermeNascimento caso você não saiba, já ouviu falar de php.ini? Nele você pode habilitar e desabilitar recursos, e um deles os drives de conexão, então existe sim uma referencia entre o PHP que ele ta usando e a configuração do ambiente, pois como eu disse, caso exista uma configuração antiga do drive do mySql setada no ambiente dele pode existir um conflito.

Comment: Exemplo: php.ini (extension=pdo_mysql). Qual versão? (resposta) A setada no ambiente. Entendeu?!

Comment: Duas versões do php não se comunicam "diretamente", logo isto não é o problema `você tem o driver MySQL restante do PHP 4.4`, provavelmente ele esta usando ou php5.6 ou 7+, o driver do mysql (independente da API) deixou de ter suporte para versões antigas do mysql, eu até imaginei que PDO seguia um caminho diferente, mas foi um engano, parece que também não suporta, talvez uma ferramenta extra a parte resolveria, mas o autor não tem como instalar isso no servidor dele, então nem tem como citar aqui.